# High voltage vanishes when increasing AC current on an X-ray supply

Tags: high-voltage, troubleshooting, x-rays

I have an old high voltage X-ray power supply enclosed in a pit of insulation oil that is difficult to operate on. The supply includes both a high voltage transformer with dual star connected rectified secondary (up to 100 kV or so fed from regular line) and an insulation transformer for lower voltage AC supply. The AC supply is connected from outside and is fully functional.

The problem is, when current from the AC supply starts to flow, the high voltage as measured from right outside the enclosure decreases significantly and progressively with more current, thus ruining the high voltage supply. Sometimes I have also noticed that it takes a lot more voltage to get the AC current to flow (even more than 100V). I am wondering where the issue most likely is, as the supply is hard to operate on.

Below is a simplified circuit diagram of the setup.
[image]
My guess is that the cable is broken somewhere between the AC insulation transformer and the output from the enclosure ("Load" in the picture), and the current severs the connection. However, I wonder if there could be other likely issues in the setup, especially considering the high voltage cable is perhaps not that likely failure point, and there is a lot more cable on the transformers comparatively.

Comment: ...what is the point of those diodes? This transformer wouldn't work.

Comment: @Hearth To turn the AC into DC or more accurately unipolar. The electron beam needs high negative voltage to push the electrons outward. A positive voltage would suck electrons instead.

Comment: Right, but... with diodes as you've drawn them here all you're going to do is saturate the transformer core and make it stop working.

Comment: @Hearth Hmm... I wonder if I made an error in transcribing the circuit from memory. I believe it's roughly correct however, in the actual setup the secondary has two star connected transformers with I recall 6 diodes in parallel - according to the circuit drawing anyway, which itself may be incorrect. Not sure if this makes a difference to your point...

Comment: @Hearth The supply has worked previously so the issue is only in the circuit diagram. I found it dubious that the low voltage AC supply could disrupt the high voltage supply directly, although that is very much related to the question.

Comment: You are probably referring to a three-phase diode bridge, which looks nothing like what you've drawn here.

Comment: @Hearth Quite possibly! Now updated schematic with three phase rectifier, which I am still not 100% is correct.. the unit has two star transformers for one, but perhaps the question is possible to answer regardless.